# bring the previous (first defibed) div in front of the next (second) div with default position

Tags: css, html, z-index

I have 2 `div`s and want the first defined `div` (which is called `befront`) to be front of the `div` defined right after that (which is called `beback`).

Using `position: absolute;` corrupts the design, so I just want to use `z-index` which does not work.

I have used the following CSS but no luck:

```
#befront {
    width:100%; height:20px; background:red;
    /* I expect that the rex box be in front of the yellow box*/
    margin-bottom:-20px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#beback {
    width:100%; height:20px; background:yellow;z-index:1;
}
```

[jsfiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCvFh/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you not just add "position: relative;" to your "#befront"?

```
#befront {
width:100%; height:20px; background:red;
/* I expect that the rex box be in front of the yellow box*/
margin-bottom:-20px;
z-index: 1000;
position: relative;
}
#beback {
width:100%; height:20px; background:yellow;z-index:1;
}
```

z-index requires that your elements be positioned in order to work correctly.

see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score 0):

try to make the `z-index` of `#beback` be negative value. change it to -1 or lower.
and add `positon` wich it's value is `absolute` or `relative`